# Sequelize define a model

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I need to use 6 tables sharing same columns. so i decided create all 6 same models where the each related to other table.

1. FooAModel,FooBModel,FooCModel,,,FooFModel in file1.ts
2. FooSchema in file2.ts

file1.ts

```
//FooAModel , FooBModel... 
export const FooAModel = db.define<FooInstance>("tableName", FooSchema, {
  ...tableOptions,
  tableName: "tableName",
  indexes: indexesPrice,
});
```

FooInstance imported from other file (Each model use the same FooInstance)

```
interface FooCreationAttributes extends Optional<Foo, "id"> {}
export interface FooInstance extends Model<Foo, FooCreationAttributes>, Foo {}
```

where Foo imported from other file

```
export interface Foo {
id:number;
x:string;
y:number;
z:boolean:
created_at:Date;
updated_at:Date;
}
```

and FooSchema imported from file2.ts

```
export const SchemaPrice = {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
x: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  },
y: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  },
z: {
    type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  },
}
```

The code works fine ,but i the problem is i dont know how to declare type to the `SchemaPrice` . i dont want to create new interface cause i want to manage all fields in same resource.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so iI figure out the answer and I write it here. Maybe it will help others.

I created two new types that are corresponding to my schema as follows:

```
type SequelizeDataTypes =
  | typeof DataTypes.INTEGER
  | typeof DataTypes.STRING
  | typeof DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  | typeof DataTypes.DATE;

type FooSchema = {
  [P in keyof Store]: {
    type: SequelizeDataTypes;
    allowNull?: boolean;
    unique?: boolean;
    autoIncrement?: boolean;
    primaryKey?: boolean;
    defaultValue?: boolean;
  };
};
```

and the SchemaPrice:

```
export const SchemaPrice: FooSchema = {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
x: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  },
y: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  },
z: {
    type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  },
}
```